Undetectable Chrome Driver in Google Colab?
I am trying to run a selenium code in Google Colab.
But I need a driver which is undetectable because I need to login to gmail.
What I have tried so far -

google_colab_selenum (undetected version) - https://github.com/jpjacobpadilla/Google-Colab-Selenium

Seleniumbase


I am getting the below same error for both the packages -
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222
from chrome not reachable
Here are all the commands that I am trying before running code -
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt-get install -y chromium-browser
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
%pip install google-colab-selenium[undetected]

And ere is the simple code I am trying to initiate the driver -
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import google_colab_selenium as 
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = gs.UndetectedChrome()
driver = Driver(uc=True, headless=True)

What are the other alternatives?

Found the answer. You should install regular Chrome and not chromium-browser.
Thanks Michael for answering - https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/discussions/2931
